# Component is not re-rendering on state update

Tags: javascript, react-redux

The component is not rendering on state update, even the mapStateToProps is executing successfully.

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import AddItem from './addItemComponent';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import RenderItem from './RenderItem';

class HomeComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>

                <div className="container">
                    <AddItem />
                </div>

                <div className="container">
                    {this.props.Items.length}
                </div>


            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        Items: state.auth.items

    }

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeComponent);
```

Reducers:

```
      const ItemsReducers = (state = {}, Action) => {
        if (!state.items)
            state.items = [];

        console.log("inside the reducers", state);
        var newState = Object.assign({}, state);

        switch (Action.type) {
            case 'AddItem':

                newState.items.push(Action.payload);

                return newState;
                break;

            default:
                return newState;
                break;

        }
        return newState;
    }

export default ItemsReducers;
```

To avoid mutation, I just clone the object and doing push operation. But still facing issue. It would be more helpful if I got any help.

Comment: When/where are you firing an action to trigger that reducer?

Comment: I just fire the action method on onsubmit of redux-form  "  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handlerSubmit.bind(this))}>  " . Inside the handlerSubmit function called my action method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.assign() make a shallow copy of your object, not a deep copy. So, you have a mutation !

In your example, `mapStateToProps` is executing because `state` has changed, but `items` keep the same reference. So your old `items` is equal to the new `items`, even if the length of array has changed. And `mapStateToProps` do not rerender the component if the output hasn't changed.

You need to copy your state and items like this:

```
var newState = Object.assign({}, state);
newStats.items = newState.items.slice();
```

But it's not a good way to use redux.

I recommend to use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) package with update(). It create a copy of your object without change the original source

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case: 'addItem': 
            return !state.items
                ? update(state, {items: {$set: [action.payload]}})
                : update(state, {items: {$push: [action.payload]}})

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```